# Electrical wiring help - generator

Tags: wiring, generator, single-phase

I'm trying to replace a regulator for a single phase generator. There is a symbol I don't understand.

What does this symbol mean?

[image: Unknown Symbol]

Full diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an iron core inductor - have a look here: https://components101.com/articles/introduction-to-inductors